# vba range with offset instead of strictly given rows/columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have following code (shortened):

```
    Dim rng As Range

    Range("A1:K2000").Select
                Set rng = Selection.Find(What:="MJ")
                If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                  rng.Cells.Select

    Dim furthest_row As Integer
    rng.Offset(2000, -4).Select
                    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
                    If ActiveCell.Row > furthest_row Then
                        furthest_row = ActiveCell.Row
                    End If

                    rng.Offset(2000, -3).Select
                    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
                    If ActiveCell.Row > furthest_row Then
                        furthest_row = ActiveCell.Row
                    End If
         Range("T9:T" & furthest_row).Select
                         .
                         .
                         .              
                 ElseIf rng Is Nothing Then
                Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate
               End If
      Next wrksheet
```

I need to modify the code: **Range("T9:T" & furthest_row).Select**

to code with **Offset** and **furthest_row** variable

Something like this:

```
Range(rng.Offset(3, 15), 'whole current column') & furthest_row).Select
```

I chose nearly ten combinations, but I was not successful.

TY !

Comment: you may try                                          
`Dim FurtherRow As Long`                         
`FurtherRow = 15`    `Range("T9").Offset(FurtherRow, 20).Select`

Comment: This is `Range("T9:T" & furthest_row).Select` wrong Syntax,, first is VBA doesn't allows  `"T9:T"`,, you get `Object Define Error` it should `"T9:T9"` and `Offset` has `OFFSET(Row Position, Col Position`)`.

Comment: Using the absolute links like "T9" etc. cannot be used. I must use relative links with offset, because I apply this code to files, where can be the starting row (like here "T9" as an example) in different row numbers. This is the reason, why I search word "MJ" (unique word in whole files) and then I move with offset only against "MJ". All here must be relatively positioned.

Comment: you mean to say the the Cell reference of MJ has to be used with Offset ?

Comment: exactly...everything relatively against "MJ"

Comment: ,, I can show you method to find Text & how to use the Row Number with Offset ,, then you need to use it further,, just confirm through comments .

Comment: it would be helpful I think. I confirm.

Answer (score 0):

This does not really answer your question, but is too long for a comment.  I'm not sure what you want to do with Column T, or whether you are looking for something three columns to the right of the column in which you found **`MJ`**

If you clarify exactly what you are wanting to do with regard to: ***I need to modify the code: Range("T9:T" & furthest_row).Select to code with Offset and furthest_row variable***, I suspect the answer will be obvious, especially after cleaning up the code.

There are also arguably better methods of finding the `furthest_row` using the `Range.Find` method, looking either for the last row used on the worksheet; the last row with data, the last row limited to several columns, etc.

But there are a number of issues with your code, so please carefully read the inline comments.

Also see [How to avoid using Select in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

```
'Always declare all variables
'Under Tools/Options/Editor SET to require variable declaration
'This will put Option Explicit at start of all newly created modules
Option Explicit

Sub terfuge()
 Dim rng As Range

 'I don't know of a reason to use Integer data type
 'It is limited to 2^15 and internally gets converted to a Long
 Dim furthest_row As Long
 Dim rw As Long

'Rarely is there a reason to use Select, Selection, Active, Activate, etc.
'   Use direct references instead
'It clutters the code and, if not very careful, can introduce bugs

Set rng = Range("A1:K2000").Find(What:="MJ") 'probably should add the other arguments,
                                                'as most will default to the last used, which may not be what you want
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then

        'what happens if "MJ" is in column A:D?  This next line will cause an error
        rw = rng.Offset(2000, -4).End(xlUp).Row
            If rw > furthest_row Then
                furthest_row = rw
            End If

         rw = rng.Offset(2000, -3).End(xlUp).Row
            If ActiveCell.Row > furthest_row Then
                furthest_row = ActiveCell.Row
            End If


         Range("T9:T" & furthest_row).Select
'
'
'


                 ElseIf rng Is Nothing Then
                Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate
               End If
'      Next wrksheet
End Sub
```

Comment: The full code is very long and functional. But I use older code with absolute linking. Now I must transform the code to relative linking. I am successful, except the code I signed as bold.
The original code: Range("T9:T" & furthest_row).Select choose specific rows with reduced range (furthest_row), fulfilling some criterias and insert some data there.
The new code: "T9:T" must be with relative referencing.

This is, why I search word "MJ" (unique word in every files) and then I move with offset only against "MJ". All here must be relatively positioned.

Comment: @Misek What happened when you adapted what I showed you for the first two instances of determining `furthest_row` to whatever column you want to look at instead of column `T`?  The examples are for relative offsets from `MJ`.  Just use the same syntax, with your desired offsets.

Comment: I try to answer some questions from you then.
'I don't know of a reason to use Integer data type
 'It is limited to 2^15 and internally gets converted to a Long
**furtest_row will never exceeds number of 2000, so the Integer is correct I think**
'probably should add the other arguments,
'as most will default to the last used, which may not be what you want
**The code relating to your comments is correct. No changes requested.**

Comment: 'what happens if "MJ" is in column A:D?  This next line will cause an error
**„MJ“ is always in A1:K2000, what is specified in my code correctly. I have to find „MJ“ between these columns, not only A:D. To answer your question: It happens, the code will search for the „MJ“ between A:D only.**

Comment: @Misek If `MJ` is found in Column D (4th column), then your line `rng.Offset(2000, -4)` will resolve to `Row 2000, Column 0` and return an error, since there is no column `0`

Comment: @Misek With regard to using `Integer`, it won't return an error if the row will never be more than 2000.  But since VBA internally converts it to a `Long` anyway, it is less efficient.

Comment: Dear Ron, "MJ" cell is usually located in column "G" although I am searching in A:K columns. However, the code is correct without error. But now I understand your ask with A:D columns. I know, what you mean. If the "MJ" is located somewhere between A:D columns, the code `rng.Offset(2000, -4)` would be wrong, but it will never happen I hope :-)

Answer (score 0):

## Caveat:

This code is partial solution, demanded by OP, shows how to use Variable, comprises `Row number`, with **O**FFSET.

```
Sub FindRowNubmer()

Dim FindRow As Range
Set FindRow = Range("A:K").Find(What:="MJ", _
               LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  MatchCase:=False)

    Range("A1").Offset(FindRow.Row - 1, 1).Select
    Range("A1").Offset(FindRow.Row + 1, 1).Value = "Found MJ in Row: " & FindRow.Row

End Sub
```

**N.B.**

- **F**ind method returns Row Number to `FindRow` variable.
- `FindRow.Row` reads the Row Number.
- `Range("A1).`, is used as benchmark.

  `Range("A1").Offset(FindRow.Row - 1, 1).Select`
- Place cell pointer on the Row, code finds search string `MJ`.

`Offset(FindRow.Row + 1, 1).Value`

- Handles manipulation with Row & displays search string along with `Row Number`, which is an **o**ptional code line (*for better understanding*).

*You may adjust Column, Row & Cell references as needed.*

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand it. I try to tell it very easily:
the code: 
`Range("T9:T2000" & furthest_row).Select` I need to modify to 
`Range(rng.Offset(3, 15), rng.Offset(2000, 15)) & furthest_row).Select`
But this syntax is wrong and must be changed.

Comment: @Misek,, read comments above `you mean,,` & `exactly...everything relatively against "MJ"` ,, and this code is all around that only!!