# VBA - Runtime error 91 on something simple?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Got a Runtime Error 91 on a simple search for ID... Why?  (SOLVED: Search failed because cell was formatted as number with comma -- weird but true, changed format to "general" and it works perfectly!  Thank you, guys!)

```
Public Sub SearchID()
      Dim foundCell As Range
      Dim searchEmpID As String
      Dim searchRange As Range
      Dim rowFound As Integer

      searchEmpID = "EmpID_0112"
      Set searchRange = Sheets("HoursData").Range("DY2:DY999")
      Sheets("HoursData").Select
      Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(What:=searchEmpID, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

MsgBox Sheets("HoursData").Range("DY115").Value   '<<<<< The data/ID is there, please see screenshot.

```
      rowFound = foundCell.Row      '<<<<<<<<<<<< Why this produces Runtime Error 91/Object Variable Not Set...???

End Sub
```

[image: The data is there, no problem.]

[image: The data is there exactly 'EmpID_0112' as you can see.]

Comment: the find is not finding anything and as such `foundCell` is nothing.

Comment: But the it's there in Row 115 exactly as "EmpID_0112"

Comment: make sure there are no spaces or other non printable characters in the data.  You are looking at the whole of the cell and if there is anything like a space or other characters in the cell then it will not be found.

Comment: change the new line to `MsgBox "'" & Sheets("HoursData").Range("DY115").Value & "'"` and show what is shown.

Comment: Also are you sure the `I` is upper case `I` and not lower case `l`?

Comment: Yes very sure!  I have done this ID search 100 times in other subroutines.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and inspect the contents of `foundCell` manually using the immediate window.

Comment: It works for me if I copy and paste the search value in a sheet.  so It is not the code.

Comment: Scott, thank you!  Solved!!  The reason is because of format.  I formatted the cell as "," and therefore is slightly indented.  Wow, the search failed because of formatting as number with comma! Learned something new!  Thanks again, Scott -- solved!

Comment: See what the [Excel member may return nothing](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ExcelMemberMayReturnNothing) Rubberduck inspection points out in your code.

Comment: If the problem is solved, then please put the solution in an answer to your question (you can answer your own question) so others will know it is solved

Comment: @SofiaEd,, [Check this link](https://superuser.com/questions/1483015/vba-range-with-offset-instead-of-strictly-given-rows-columns/1483403?noredirect=1#comment2237382_1483403) , find VBA code I've posted finds the `Row number` for the `Search String`.